# Error when opening Discover on KDE Neon

Tags: kde-neon

When I open Discover to install system updates or update apps I get a popup with this error:

```
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi' E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

May or may not be related but I also get this when I try to run `sudo apt-get update` in the terminal:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

Tried some of the solutions [in this Ask Ubuntu thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/480908/problem-with-update-manager-no-module-named-apt-pkg-in-ubuntu-13-10-having-i) but am still having the issue.

Comment: Welcome to U&L. That's not a KDE error, it's an operating system error - so what exactly is your OS? Please [deit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/738824/edit) the question to add new info instead of answering in comments - that way the relevant info is readily available and the question stays up-to-date.

Comment: @Peregrino69 Not sure what you mean, the OS is KDE neon in the title. Do you need the version number?

Comment: KDE [isn't a distro](https://neon.kde.org/faq#is-it-a-distro) i.e. operating system. It's a desktop manager and package archive you can install to any Linux distro like Ubuntu, Debian, Gentoo, Fedora etc. etc., and Neon is its latest iteration. Give commands `cat /etc/os-release`, `uname -a`, `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d` and [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/738824/edit) your question to add the outputs. Please enclose all outputs in the code brackets `{ }` to preserve the formatting.